# Issue with parse dashboard

Tags: android, heroku, parse-platform

I'm not able to run parse dashboard on my browser. But I have set up my parse-dashboard-config.json as

```
{
"apps": [{
"serverURL": "http://instagram312345.herokuapp.com/parse",
"appId": "instagram349322jfd38Hdf",
"masterKey": "defjkDJFKDfjfk343dfkjJSF",
"appName": "Instagram",
"iconName": ""
  }],
"iconsFolder": "icons"
}
```

but on running parse-dashboard from node.js command line with

```
parse-dashboard --config parse-dashboard-config.json
```

i get the result

```
The dashboard is now available at http://0.0.0.0:4040/
```

but when i load parse dashboard i get the error

```
"Server not reachable:unauthorized:master key is required"
```

but as you can see in the config json file. I have provided the masterKey too.

[screenshot of my browser at url: http://localhost:4040](https://i.stack.imgur.com/to3rX.png)

Answer (score 0):

I got your points very well, Here It might be occur due to Secure Heroku domain ServerURL. After make necessary changes in parse-dashboard-config.json file you have to fire bellow command when your local Parse Dashboard get to install
It seems like:

1) You have to first run index.js file from Parse-server-example before to fire below steps
    command:  npm start

after that you will get below message

> parse-server-example@1.0.0 start /home/kirtikant/parse-server-example
>   node index.js
>   parse-server-example running on port 1337.

Now open another terminal and follow this steps

1) Reach location where your parse dashboard is install into your local system

kirtikant@kirtikant_learn: $ cd /user/local/lib/node_modules/parse-dashboard/Parse Dashboard

2) press 'enter'. fire this command to make necessary changes in parse-dashboard-config.json file

sudo nano parse-dashboard-config.json

3) now run your .json file by using below command:

parse-dashboard --config parse-dashboard-config.json allowInsecureHTTP

4) press 'enter' you will get bellow message

The dashboard is now available at http://0.0.0.0:4040/

Now your local parse-dashboard is in running state. Open your browser and write

https://localhost:4040/  or https://127.0.0.1:4040/